# Why does listFiles() also list directories as files?

Tags: java, file, directory, filesystems

Seems the method listFiles() also lists all directories and threats all results as directories.

Comment: If you prefer you can list their names instead.

Comment: The name of a file or directory doesn't matter. You cna have a file called `...` in unix. and a directory can have an extension in Windows. e.g. the "special" directories have extension like `.{ABED-7862368923-ABFE}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object in Java can represent either a file or a directory. You can check whether it's a file or a directory by [`isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) and [`isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()).

Comment: @Daniel: please don't try to post code in a comment as it can't be formatted and isn't readable. If you need to post code, then edit your original post and post a comment directing Eng. to your original post changes.

Answer (score 3):

Directories are it self files but it is special kind of file in filesystem.

In java `isDirectory()` returns true if it is directory .

Comment: never thought about this that a directory is also a file, this is very confusing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing uncommon for it to list both files and directories. The [File.listFiles() API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) says:

> **Returns:
>       An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories** in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

[java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is just an abstract representation of file and directory pathnames. There is isFile() and isDirectory() methods to tell apart.

Comment: Your quoted text is wrong.  When I click on your link, I see the following: `Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname.`

Comment: its been a long time, apis change :D

Answer (score 1):

File Is an `abstract` representation of `file` and `directory` **pathnames**.

An `instance` of `File` Class in Java represents either a `file` or a `directory`.

Thats the reason we can use `isDirectory()` and `isFile()` on the same file object to check whether its a file or directory.